# React: How can I make a loading screen that only appears when initially loading the website?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to render the component AnimatedLogo when the app initially loads, but every time the route is changed, AnimatedLogo shows again. I'd like for it to only happen when the entire app loads / reloads. What's the best course of action / solution?

```
function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(false)
            console.log("setLoading -> false")
        }, 2300);
    }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
       {loading ? (<AnimatedLogo/>) :
          <Router>
            <Navbar/>
            <Socials/>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Description/>}/> 
              <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
            </Routes>
          </Router>      
        }    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `every time the route is changed, AnimatedLogo shows again` I wouldn't expect that from the code you provided... Are you using `useNavigate` to change to a new route, or something else?

Comment: I'm manually changing the route in the URL currently, I haven't set up any links for it yet. Do you think it will act differently after setting that up? @NicholasTower

Comment: Setting up the buttons to change routes solved this, thanks for the response @NicholasTower. Who knows how long I would have kept trying to mess with useEffect before realizing this haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the URL manually causes this issue. I simply had to set up the buttons that take the user to the specified routes and the loading screen no longer shows.